# Dynamic Range used Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic, range

I have a series of number of my column A,, from A1 to A100 going from 1 to 9

Now I want to count the number of times the number 1 appears, it is easy:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100;1)
```

Second step I want to count only on the 12 last values, still easy:

```
=COUNTIF(A89:A100;1)
```

Third step, I want to dynamise that, for when I add a new value on my cell A101, the formula change automatically like that:

```
=COUNTIF(A90:A101;1)
```

I already managed to get the number of filled cells like that:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;"<>"&"")
```

So theorically I sould do something like:

```
=COUNTIF("A"& (COUNTIF(A:A;"<>"&"")-11) & ":A" & COUNTIF(A:A;"<>"&"");1)
```

But it doesn't work :(

Can someone helps me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTA directly counts non-empty cells.

The generated result is a text, therefore must use INDIRECT to transform it to a range.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"& (COUNTA(A:A)-11) & ":A" & COUNTA(A:A));1)
```

Comment: While this is a working solution, my advise would be to not use INDIRECT unless you have to. If it's a fixed range you're referring to, you can always create the same logic using INDEX making it non-volatile. Volatile functions like for instance OFFSET, INDIRECT will recalculate at any change within the file, and often have good alternatives (like JvdV's post).

Answer (score 2):

Fun question. Instead of `COUNTIF()`, use something along these lines:

```
=SUM(--(TAKE(TOCOL(A:A,3),-12)=1))
```

This would mean:

- `TOCOL(A:A,3)` - Remove all empty cells from column A:A and return an array of only all values;
- `TAKE(<Step1>,-12)` - Return the last 12 values;
- `SUM(--(<Step2>=1))` - Check how often any of these last values equals 1 and use a double unary to transform the boolean values into 1/0 to be able to sum the results in a total.

---

If you don't have access to these new DA-functions try to use a semi-volatile construct where you utilize `INDEX()` to create the range of interest:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)-11):INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)),1)
```